# Which ship became the flagship of Starfleet after Enterprise-D was destroyed?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship

It is mentioned a couple of times throughout The Next Generation that the USS Enterprise-D is the [flagship of the Federation/Starfleet](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Flagship#United_Federation_of_Planets). After the Enterprise's destruction in the movie Generations which ship became the new flagship?

Comment: Nice Q; never occurred to me. I can't imagine they just went without one until E was ready,  altho maybe... don't think it was TOO long a time.

Comment: I find the notion to call it flagship quite useless (I understand that they canonically do). After all Starfleets vessels often operate alone and not as a group of ships. And if they form groups on special occasions the most fitting ship of that group and probably the senior command officer assumes command and therefore the flagship. If loosely interpreted as just the "best ship" in the fleet it could be assumed that after destruction of the 1701-D the next Galaxy-class ship would be the flagship.

Comment: @Ghanima Useless or not, real-world navies often have flagships. For example, HMS Bulwark is the flagship of the Royal Navy.

Comment: Another renown navy does not maintain a flagship for the whole fleet. What's the point ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Federation is not using the common naval terms for flagship.  One is the ship on which the admiral's flag is being flown.  Picard, for all he pwns admirals in debate, is not a flag officer so that can't be it.  However, when Admiral Riker uses the term in All Good Things, this is what he means.

The second is the ship leading a fleet.  The OP observed that the Enterprise is rarely leading a fleet and certainly not the whole Federation fleet.

They're using it to mean the Enterprise represents the best Starfleet has to offer.  It gets the best pick of crew, strives to have the best service record, and has the best all round capabilities.  In some way it is a political and diplomatic designation.  Sending a Galaxy class ship means the Federation thinks it's important, but if you want to make someone feel *really* important you send the flagship.

The designation is honorary, the Federation doesn't need a flagship.  I would say there is no canon evidence to support that there was a Federation flagship after 1701-D.  However, there's also no canon evidence to say there *wasn't* a new flagship.

It's never said, but one possibility is the 1701-E was made flagship.  There was only a year between [the destruction of the 1701-D](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28NCC-1701-D%29) and [the launching of the 1701-E](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28NCC-1701-E%29).  Since the flagship title is honorary, there would be no pressing need to designate a temporary flagship.  However, given it's poor performance in the movies, the very aggressive nature of the Sovereign class, and that the hull was going to be given a different designation and name until the D blew up, I have my doubts the E was ever flagship.

Comment: Poor performance?!? Blasphemy!!!

Answer (score -2):

I cannot remember which TNG episode(s) mention this following piece of info, but the USS Yorktown was noted as the 'sister' ship to the Enterprise D. So maybe the Yorktown would take the title (honorary or not) of the Federation Flagship during the year between an Enterprise-less Starfleet. Also, in ST: First Contact, Geordie mentioned the Sovereign Class Enterprise was the "most advanced starship in the fleet", which would lead you to think that it would probably the best crew in the fleet also... would hold that title again of Flagship.

I would love to hear anyone else's point of view on this.

Comment: You may be thinking of the USS Yamato, which was destroyed in TNG "Contagion".

Answer (score -2):

The USS Defiant is given to Sisko/Deep Space Nine (Later and technically also Worf) in 2371 before the destruction of the USS Enterprise-D

(*The Search*is listed as the first series of episodes in the Timeline on Memory Alpha for the year 2371.)

While not making the most sense as it's not what Starfleet supposedly represents, it's not officially recognized as a warship at the time. Some even consider the USS Defiant as Starfleet's Flagship of the Dominion War.

The USS Defiant has a lot going for it as it is captained by the commander of an important Starfleet* installation. It could be used as a sign of good faith between the Bajorans and Romulans, having Bajors Emissary to the Prophets and a Romulan cloaking device. The Flagships do have state of the art Starfleet technology, and  I can't think of anything more state of the art at the time for its purpose (other than Delta Quadrant tech the USS Voyager borrowed,) than, quantum torpedoes, cloaking devices, ablative bull armor, warp 9.9 and phaser pulse cannons.

The USS Defiant doesn't make the best case, but at least it has a better case than Voyager.

Comment: Having the Defiant be the flagship of the Federation makes zero sense. It's basically a small weapons platform with an engine.